# Config merging in babelv7

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I just upgraded to babelv7 , earlier I had a default environment which had some aliases and a test environment which had some aliases, now in the test environment babel used to merge both the configs, in babelv7 this functionality has been removed ,how to achieve this merging functionality without repeating the aliases 2 times.

This is my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['custom-preset'],
  env: {
    test: {
      presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
      plugins: [
        'transform-class-properties',
        [
          'module-resolver',
          {
            root: ['./app'],
            alias: {
              'test-util': './node_modules/test-util/lib',
            },
          },
        ],
      ],
    },
  },
  ignore: ['node_modules'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'transform-imports',
      {
        lodash: {
          transform: 'lodash/${member}',
          preventFullImport: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./app'],
        alias: {
          'module1': './src/components/module1',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary change to merging in Babel 7 is that things are actually merged *more*, so instead of this config producing *two* instances of `module-resolver` with two different configs, the one in `test` will *overwrite* the config for the module in the top-level.

To tell Babel that they are meant to be two independent plugins, you need to give at least one of them a unique name, which is a string passed as the third entry in the plugin item array, e.g.

```
  plugins: [
    'transform-class-properties',
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./app'],
        alias: {
          'test-util': './node_modules/test-util/lib',
        },
      },
      'testing-resolver' // A name for the plugin so it is unique and doesn't overwrite
    ],
  ],
```

Comment: Thank you, Is it written in the docs somewhere , not able to find it

Comment: It is mentioned in the plugin merging section in https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#plugin-preset-merging, but not specifically in the context of `env`.